# J1 Forth CPU program understanding

Tags: forth, gforth

I really feel it is difficult to understand the J1 Forth CPU programming.

I have basic understanding of Forth, but I couldn't understand the words defined in J1 Forth programming like d# and h#...and how is it dealing with I/O peripherals?

Answer (score 2):

The existence of the `d#` and `h#` words is just a consequence of the chosen compiler implementation method.

The code written for **J1** is actually running on the hosting Forth system. The program for **J1**, though looking exactly like a Forth source, is just a list of words that are executed by hosting system (Gforth) sequentially, as read from file. And only when the word is executed, it adds the actual **J1** instruction to the final image.

With that approach, only words that are executing are able to produce instructions for **J1**. Numeric literals aren't those words, so they had to be wrapped with calls to `d#` (decimal number) or `h#` (hexadecimal number). Without wrapping, literals would put numbers on the compiler stack and won't add any instruction for **J1** to execute.

The peripherals are typically mapped into memory space or I/O space. You'd put a value to write, and the address of peripheral on stack, and issue the store command appropriate for the selected space. Address spaces may be distinct, or just one common - depending on the actual **J1** version or implementation details. The original **J1** had a single address space; your RAM and peripherals would be addressed uniformly with `!` and `@` words. The **J1a** version has dedicated I/O space, and include additional `io@` / `io!` words.

Personally I find the **J1a** a better version. But I don't use the **SwapForth** - a complete Forth system for **J1a**, and instead extended the `cross.fs` to include the words, primitives and facilities I need, because I really need only an offline compiler rather than a complete system capable of building own code on the fly.